# Magento Observer is not able to run the script

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, soap

I have written a script in Magento observer to send the invoice number in my ERP at the time of invoice creation. Below is my script. I am using `sales_order_invoice_save_after` event for the below job.

```
public function invoicePull(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){

        $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
        $InvoiceId = $invoice->getData('increment_id');
        mail('it_magento@mysoresareeudyog.com', 'Invoice Pulled', $InvoiceId);

        $proxy = new SoapClient('http://182.72.91.202/XCerptRef/XCerptService.asmx?wsdl');
        $result = $proxy->PullInvoice(array('InvoiceId' => $InvoiceId));
        return($result);
    }
```

However, I am able to receive email, but the api script is not working in the above code. The same script I have tested in a separate PHP file in the root of Magento, And that works fine.

Here is my simple php script to run the same job.

```
<?php

$InvoiceId = 'MSUL000000006757';
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://182.72.91.202/XCerptRef/XCerptService.asmx?wsdl');
$proxy->PullInvoice(array('InvoiceId' => $InvoiceId));

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Change your code:**

```
   public function invoicePull(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){

        $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
        $invoiceId = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice()->getOrigData('entity_id');
        if(is_null($invoiceId )){
            $InvoiceId = $invoice->getIncrementId();
            mail('it_magento@mysoresareeudyog.com', 'Invoice Pulled', $InvoiceId);
            try{
                $proxy = new SoapClient('http://182.72.91.202/XCerptRef/XCerptService.asmx?wsdl');
                $result = $proxy->PullInvoice(array('InvoiceId' => $InvoiceId));
            }catch(Exception $e){

            }
            //return($result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, It is not working @Amit

Comment: are your mail funtion give the invoice id at your mail?

Comment: Yes I am getting invoice id everytime

Comment: that mean your issue soap code .please fix it

Comment: I am running the same soap code in simple php file. And it is working very file. I have a `abc.php` file in magento root folder with that plain php script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE))
```

it should work

Comment: It is not working...